# Calculate the mean between several columns of df2 that can vary according to the variable `var1` of df1 and add the value to a new variable in df1

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame `df1` that summarises the depth of different fishes over time at different places.

On the other hand, I have `df2` that summarises the intensity of the currents over time (EVERY THREE HOURS) from the surface to 39 meters depth at intervals of 8 meters (`m0-7`, `m8-15`, `m16-23`, `m24-31` and `m32-39`) in a specific place. As an example:

```
df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16"),Site=c("BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD"),Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")


> df1
             Datetime Site Ind Depth
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0
5 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 18:00:00","2016-08-01 21:00:00","2016-08-02 00:00:00"), Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),var3=c(2.75,4,5.75,2.25,1.4),var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,2.75,3.4),var5=c(3,4,4.75,3,1.7))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

> df2
             Datetime Site m0-7 m8-15 m16-23 m24-31 m32-39
1 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD 2.75  3.00   2.75   3.25   3.00
2 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD 4.00  4.00   4.00   3.00   4.00
3 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD 6.75  4.75   5.75   6.50   4.75
4 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD 2.25  3.00   2.25   2.75   3.00
5 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD 4.30  2.10   1.40   3.40   1.70
```

I want to create a variable in `df1` that reflects the mean current for the depth layers in which the fish WASN'T. For instance, if fish is at 20 meters depth, which corresponds to the layer `m16-23`, I want to know the mean current for the layers `m0-7`, `m8-15`, `m24-31` and `m32-39`.

Note1: if my fish was to a depth higher than 39 meters, I consider it as if it was at the deepest layer (`m32-39`). An example of this in row 4 of `df1`.

Note2: since the current records are every three hours, every hour indicated in `df2$Datetime` represents one hour and a half more, and one hour and a half less. That is, the current intensity pointed out in `df2` at `21:00:00` reflects the currents between `19:30:00` and `22:30:00`. The same with the rest of the hours.

I would expect this:

```
> df1
             Datetime Site Ind Depth current.Mean
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3         3.75
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0           NA
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4         5.94
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0         5.94
5 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA           NA
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1         2.87
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question comprises interesting challenges:

1. The OP is asking for a *"partial anti-join"*, i.e., the OP wants to aggregate current data in `df2` where `Datetime` and `Site` are matching but the depth layer does *not*.
2. The current data `df2` are given in a look-up table where each value is associated with a *depth range* (depth layer) and a *time range* of 3 hours. So, the measured `Depth` and `Datetime` in `df1` need to be mapped onto the respective ranges.

I have tried different approaches but I ended up with the one below which does not make assumptions about the aggregate function. So, `mean()` can be called directly.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# reshape df2 from wide to long format
currents <- melt(setDT(df2), id.vars = c("Datetime", "Site"),
                 variable.name = "layer", value.name = "current")

# create columns to join on
labels <- names(df2) %>% stringr::str_subset("^m")
breaks <- c(seq(0, 32, 8), Inf)
setDT(df1)[, layer := cut(Depth, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)]
df1[, current.dt := df2[df1, on = .(Site, Datetime), 
                      roll = "nearest", x.Datetime]]

# "partial anti-join" to compute mean of other layers
currents_other_layers <- 
  currents[df1, on = .(Site, Datetime = current.dt)][
    layer != i.layer, mean(current), by = .(i.Datetime, Site)]

# append result column
df1[currents_other_layers, on = .(Site, Datetime = i.Datetime), current.mean := i.V1]
df1
```

> ```
>                Datetime Site Ind Depth  layer          current.dt current.mean
> 1: 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3   m0-7 2016-08-01 15:00:00       3.7500
> 2: 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0 m16-23                <NA>           NA
> 3: 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4 m32-39 2016-08-01 18:00:00       5.9375
> 4: 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0 m32-39 2016-08-01 18:00:00       5.9375
> 5: 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA   <NA> 2016-08-01 21:00:00           NA
> 6: 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1 m16-23 2016-08-02 00:00:00       2.8750
> ```

This reproduces OP's expected result.

#### Explanation

`df2` is reshaped from wide to long format. This allows for joining / anti-joining on the `layer` column.

```
currents
```

> ```
>                Datetime Site  layer current
>  1: 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD   m0-7    2.75
>  2: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD   m0-7    4.00
>  3: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD   m0-7    6.75
>  4: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD   m0-7    2.25
>  5: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD   m0-7    4.30
>  6: 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD  m8-15    3.00
>  7: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD  m8-15    4.00
>  8: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD  m8-15    4.75
>  9: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD  m8-15    3.00
> 10: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD  m8-15    2.10
> 11: 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD m16-23    2.75
> 12: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD m16-23    4.00
> 13: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m16-23    5.75
> 14: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD m16-23    2.25
> 15: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD m16-23    1.40
> 16: 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD m24-31    3.25
> 17: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD m24-31    3.00
> 18: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m24-31    6.50
> 19: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD m24-31    2.75
> 20: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD m24-31    3.40
> 21: 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD m32-39    3.00
> 22: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD m32-39    4.00
> 23: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m32-39    4.75
> 24: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD m32-39    3.00
> 25: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD m32-39    1.70
>                Datetime Site  layer current
> ```

Now, `df1` has to be amended to include columns which correspond to `layer` and `Datetime` in `currents`.

For `Depth`, the `cut()` function is used. The last layer level `m32-39` is extended to `Inf` so all depths greater 32 m are included in this level as requested by the OP.

For `Datetime`, a rolling join to the *nearest* `Datetime` in `df2` is used. This is possible because `df2$Datetime` denotes the mid-point of the 3 hour time range.

After `df1` has been prepared, we can do the "partial anti-join". Unfortunately, `data.table`'s non-equi joins does not accept the `!=` operator. So, we cannot write

```
currents[df1, on = .(Datetime = current.dt, Site, layer != layer)]
```

directly but have to use a work-around where we first pick the rows where we expect matches and then do an anti-join:

```
 currents[df1, on = .(Datetime = current.dt, Site)][
    !df1, on = .(Datetime = current.dt, Site, layer)]
```

> ```
>                Datetime Site  layer current          i.Datetime Ind Depth i.layer
>  1: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD  m8-15    4.00 2016-08-01 15:34:07  16   5.3    m0-7
>  2: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD m16-23    4.00 2016-08-01 15:34:07  16   5.3    m0-7
>  3: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD m24-31    3.00 2016-08-01 15:34:07  16   5.3    m0-7
>  4: 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD m32-39    4.00 2016-08-01 15:34:07  16   5.3    m0-7
>  5: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD   m0-7    6.75 2016-08-01 17:29:16  19  36.4  m32-39
>  6: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD  m8-15    4.75 2016-08-01 17:29:16  19  36.4  m32-39
>  7: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m16-23    5.75 2016-08-01 17:29:16  19  36.4  m32-39
>  8: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m24-31    6.50 2016-08-01 17:29:16  19  36.4  m32-39
>  9: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD   m0-7    6.75 2016-08-01 18:33:16  16  42.0  m32-39
> 10: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD  m8-15    4.75 2016-08-01 18:33:16  16  42.0  m32-39
> 11: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m16-23    5.75 2016-08-01 18:33:16  16  42.0  m32-39
> 12: 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD m24-31    6.50 2016-08-01 18:33:16  16  42.0  m32-39
> 13: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD   m0-7    2.25 2016-08-01 20:54:16  17    NA    <NA>
> 14: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD  m8-15    3.00 2016-08-01 20:54:16  17    NA    <NA>
> 15: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD m16-23    2.25 2016-08-01 20:54:16  17    NA    <NA>
> 16: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD m24-31    2.75 2016-08-01 20:54:16  17    NA    <NA>
> 17: 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD m32-39    3.00 2016-08-01 20:54:16  17    NA    <NA>
> 18: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD   m0-7    4.30 2016-08-01 22:48:16  16  22.1  m16-23
> 19: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD  m8-15    2.10 2016-08-01 22:48:16  16  22.1  m16-23
> 20: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD m24-31    3.40 2016-08-01 22:48:16  16  22.1  m16-23
> 21: 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD m32-39    1.70 2016-08-01 22:48:16  16  22.1  m16-23
> 22:                <NA>   HG   <NA>      NA 2016-08-01 16:25:16  17  24.0  m16-23
>                Datetime Site  layer current          i.Datetime Ind Depth i.layer
> ```

This can be aggregated as desired by an arbitrary aggregation function (no need to manually add single columns selectively):

```
currents_other_layers <- 
  currents[df1, on = .(Datetime = current.dt, Site)][
    !df1, on = .(Datetime = current.dt, Site, layer)][
      !is.na(Depth), mean(current), by = .(i.Datetime, Site)]

currents_other_layers
```

> ```
>             i.Datetime Site     V1
> 1: 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD 3.7500
> 2: 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD 5.9375
> 3: 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD 5.9375
> 4: 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD 2.8750
> 5: 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG     NA
> ```

This result contains the average currents of all other layers except the observed layer. Note that grouping is by `i.Datetime` which refers to `df1$Datetime` and `Site`. Rows where `Depth` is missing in `df1` are omitted to meet OP's expected result.

A final *update join* appends the result column to `df1`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach this in two steps:

1. make a lookup table with avg_speed_elsewhere for each Datetime, Site, and Depth in df2.
2. Join to df1.

Here's a lookup table:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2_long <- df2 %>%
  gather(depth_rng, speed, `m0-7`:`m32-39`) %>%
  separate(depth_rng, c("min_depth", "max_depth")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("depth")), parse_number) %>%
  # EDIT -- added to make deep category cover >39 too
  mutate(max_depth = if_else(max_depth == 39, 10000, max_depth)) %>%
  group_by(Datetime, Site) %>%
  # Avg Speed elsewhere is the sum of all speeds, minus this speed, all divided by 4.
  mutate(avg_speed_elsewhere = (sum(speed) - speed) / 4)

> df2_long
# A tibble: 25 x 6
# Groups:   Datetime, Site [5]
   Datetime            Site  min_depth max_depth speed avg_speed_elsewhere
   <dttm>              <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>
 1 2016-08-18 12:00:00 BD            0         7  2.75                3   
 2 2016-08-18 15:00:00 BD            0         7  4                   3.75
 3 2016-08-18 18:00:00 BD            0         7  6.75                5.44
 4 2016-08-18 21:00:00 BD            0         7  2.25                2.75
 5 2016-08-19 00:00:00 BD            0         7  4.3                 2.15
 6 2016-08-18 12:00:00 BD            8        15  3                   2.94
 7 2016-08-18 15:00:00 BD            8        15  4                   3.75
 8 2016-08-18 18:00:00 BD            8        15  4.75                5.94
 9 2016-08-18 21:00:00 BD            8        15  3                   2.56
10 2016-08-19 00:00:00 BD            8        15  2.1                 2.7 
# ... with 15 more rows
```

I expect this will work, but your provided data doesn't overlap so I'm not sure:

```
df1 %>%
  # EDIT - replaced floor_date with round_date
  mutate(Datetime_3hr = lubridate::round_date(Datetime, "3 hour")) %>%
  left_join(df2_long, by = c("Site", "Datetime_3hr" = "Datetime")) %>%
  filter(Depth >= min_depth & Depth < max_depth + 1 | is.na(Depth))
```

Comment: Ei Jon!! Thanks for your time. I'm checking your script and I find some problems that I don't know if you know how to solve. One problem is the time allocation from `df2` to `df1`. For instance, the currents allocation to the fish recorded at `17:29:16` corresponds to the time `15:00:00` instead of the time `18:00:00`. I need to allocate to each `df1$Datetime` the closest time from `df2`. Other problem is that the code has deleted 3 out of 6 rows. It deleted the row that belongs to other `Site`, the row with `NA` in `Depth` and the row where the fish was deeper than 39 meters.

Comment: I would like to don't delete any row of them since in my real data those rows contain other valuable information that I want to keep. Aditionally, as I said in the post, for depths bigger than 39 meters, like in the case of the row 4 (==42), I want to consider as if they were in the deepest layer we have (`m32-39`).

I am looking forward to finding your new contributions if you find how to solve these problems. Thank you very much for your time again :)

Comment: Edited to use `round_date` instead of `floor_date`, and changed df2_long so that the last category covers depths beyond 39.

Comment: It is almost perfect with your last change! Do you know how to do in order to don't delete neither rows where fish depth is `NA` nor rows that correspond to a different site? Thanks for your contribution!!!

Comment: Not sure about rows that correspond to different site, but I think the adjusted filter will include NA depths as well as ones that fit. You'll get multiple matches for the NA depths since it's unknown which is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can do a rolling join between your two databases in order to associate your depth variables with your current variables even though the times don't match. What the rolling join does is associate one table with the other by which time is the closest (according to your chosen options). I changed a bit of your data so that the the days match

```
library(data.table)

df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16"),Site=c("BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD"),Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 18:00:00","2016-08-01 21:00:00","2016-08-02 00:00:00"), Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),var3=c(2.75,4,5.75,2.25,1.4),var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,2.75,3.4),var5=c(3,4,4.75,3,1.7))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df1, Site, Datetime)
setkey(df2, Site, Datetime)

df_merge = df2[df1, roll = Inf]
```

Then I use dplyr's case_when to calculate the currents for other depths

```
library(dplyr)

df_merge[, current_elsewhere := case_when(
  is.na(Depth) ~ NA_real_,
  Depth < 7 ~ (`m8-15` + `m16-23` + `m24-31` + `m32-39`)/4,
  Depth < 15 ~ (`m0-7` + `m16-23` + `m24-31` + `m32-39`)/4,
  Depth < 23 ~ (`m0-7` + `m8-15` + `m24-31` + `m32-39`)/4,
  Depth < 31 ~ (`m0-7` + `m8-15` + `m16-23` + `m32-39`)/4,
  T ~ (`m0-7` + `m8-15` + `m16-23` + `m24-31`)/4)]

df_merge
              Datetime Site m0-7 m8-15 m16-23 m24-31 m32-39 Ind Depth current_elsewhere
1: 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD 4.00  4.00   4.00   3.00   4.00  16   5.3            3.7500
2: 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD 4.00  4.00   4.00   3.00   4.00  19  36.4            3.7500
3: 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD 6.75  4.75   5.75   6.50   4.75  16  42.0            5.9375
4: 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD 6.75  4.75   5.75   6.50   4.75  17    NA                NA
5: 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD 2.25  3.00   2.25   2.75   3.00  16  22.1            2.7500
6: 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG   NA    NA     NA     NA     NA  17  24.0                NA
```

Comment: Ei @Luis, thanks for your reply! I've checked the output for `df1` and it seems to work quite well... Although there is a problem that I don't know if you know how to solve: the correct time allocation from `df2` to `df1`. For instance, `df1[1, ]` is at `15:34:07` but the currents allocation from `df2` corresponds to the time `18:00:00` instead of the time `15:00:00`. It is the same for `df1[3 , ]`. Note: I've just changed the dates for the data frame `df2` since I made a mistake and I wrote different datetimes there with regard datetimes in `df1`.

Comment: Another question, I've also found that for the row where there is no depth (`df1[5 , ]`), your scripts still calculate a current_elsewhere. In this case, for example, it estimates a current of 2.5625 at `20:54:16` according to current recordings in `df2` at `21:00:00`. But I don't know exactly how it get this mean of 2.5625 since it is not the mean among the five columns. Do you know how it calculate the current_elsewhere when there is `NA` in the column `Depth`?

Comment: @Luis, your result does not match OP's expected result. This is because you are using `roll = -Inf` which does not join with the closest but with the preceeding `Datetime`. Use `roll = "nearest"`.

Comment: Thanks Uwe. What I did, instead of `roll="nearest"`, was to create a rounded column with `round_date(df1$Datetime, "3 hour")`. After that, I runned `df_merge = df2[df1, roll = -Inf]`. Is it correct?

Comment: @Dekike You can choose whether you want to join to the closest time, the closest time after or the closest time before by choosing the appropriate "roll" option ("nearest", -Inf and Inf, respectively). If in the df2 table the 15:00 line means 12:00-15:00 you should use -Inf, and if it means 15:00-18:00, you should use Inf. As for the calculation for the line that doesn't have a depth, you're right, it wasn't taking into the account when depth was NA. Take a look at the edit (just change the is.na(Depth) in the case_when to whatever you think is best).

Comment: Oh, and if the 15:00 in df2 means the measurement taken at 15:00, "nearest" is probably the correct choice.

Comment: @Luis, your edit stil does not return OP's expected result. Also, please, re-read OP's *Note 2*: "That is, the current intensity pointed out in `df2` at 21:00:00 reflects the currents between 19:30:00 and 22:30:00."

Comment: @Dekike, if you round `df1$Datetime` to 3 hours then you don't need a rolling join; a normal join will do.

Comment: @Uwe by changing roll to "nearest" like I point out in my last comment, it returns his expected result.